# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using an `input` field to include a date picker. The code for the date picker is running perfectly if I run it alone. However when I am integrating the datepicker `input` field I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

I have also included all the necessary libraries and links for the required CSS and script.

```html
<div id="select" class="inner">
  <select id="test-options">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="date">Select date time</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="datepicker" class="inner">
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker-input"></p>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#test-options').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'date') {
      var $datepicker = $("#datepicker-input");
      $datepicker.datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
          $(input).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
        }
      });
      $datepicker.datepicker("show");
    }
  });
});
```

```js
if ($(this).attr('type'))
  input['type'] = $(this).attr('type');

// this is what causes the error:
input['questions'] = $(this).attr('data-conv-question').split("|");
```

Comment: This error presents when the element does not have the attribute `data-conv-question`.. so check the element is already has this attribute first

Comment: How is `data-conv-question` set? If it's done using `data()` then the attribute won't be in the DOM and will always return `undefined`. You'd need to use `data()` as the getter as well. The code in your question is not enough to fully diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, **the fact you are looking for an input but there is none**.

`questions` and `data-conv-question` ***are texts of a span element*** `<span></span>`.

Take a look at the fixed example, although produces no result for questions, still working:

[Working js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0b4gakm3/).

Fill free to play with it as much as you want, but be sure you are pointing at the correct elements in your code.